# How to add/remove selected attribute to option onchange MooTools?

Tags: javascript, html-select, mootools

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tE6Wv/7/

I need to add or remove from previously selected option attribute `selected="selected"` to the option on change with moo , but the html is never added.

I am slo creating the menu with moo but selected value is not taken

```
var firstoption = new Element('option', { 
    'selected':'selected', 
    'value':"myValue" 
}
```

or

```
var firstoption = new Element('option', {
    'selected': true,
    'value': "myValue"
}
```

none of these work

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do - when the change happens, the selected will change by itself - you don't need to change it yourself.  FWIW, the fiddle currently is currently trying to set a property on selectedIndex, which is an integer, not a DOM element.

Comment: the issue also is with `<select id="menu" onchange="location.href=this.value">` - this.value does not map to anything useful. `this.get('value')` will return the selected value via the mootools accessor. so `location.href = this.get('value')` - and you really ought to avoid using inline js, just add the change event like you do in the fiddle, not in the markup

Comment: the select changes but my selected option resets back to Go to instead the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you can change your fiddle to confirm that selected is already being changed for you as such.  I've assigned id's to the 2 options just to make it a little easier to tell:

html change to include id attributes on the 2 link options:

```
<select id="menu" onchange="location.href=this.value">
    <option value="">Go to..</option>
    <option id="link1" value="#">Link</option>
    <option id="link2" value="#">Link</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

js to show the selected changes already:

```
$('menu').addEvent('change',function() {
    alert(document.getElementById('link1').selected);
    alert(document.getElementById('link2').selected);
});​
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the change event with a select element. In IE, when navigating using the cursor keys, a change event is dispatched every time the key is pressed so the user will not get beyond the next option from the currently selected one before being sent to the new page.

Comment: I cant target them by id because I will never know which one is next. They are auto generated. I need selected one to stay selected and not reset back to first option

Comment: @Benn - you don't need to add id's - I just did so to show you that selected was getting changed already.  You don't need to change it yourself.